# Stream video from my webcam to my website (ideally under a html5 player)

Tags: video, streaming, webcam

I will like to stream video (webcam) from a pc (windows or linux) to my website. The ideal scenario I will like to achieve is to stream live video that is shown on my site background, like a html5 video background but live. Im pretty sure this have been done several times, do you know any examples or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Icecast + avconv/ffmpeg/gstreamer should be able to do what you want.

I've posted some proof of concept in the past on [google+](https://plus.google.com/+icecast/posts/iPsLfVaJ95C) that you could use as the starting point. Both avconv and ffmpeg should work fine nowadays.

On the HTML side you can just use the  tag to reference the stream. You'll want to run the Icecast server on the same server as your web server and not at home, as video streaming can consume quite a bit of bandwidth.